# Webpack: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am creating React app from scratch. At some point I encountered an error like in the title when I am building my app with webpack.

[Here is a minimal repository to reproduce this error.](https://gitlab.com/ReFruity/documentisnotdefined)

What is the problem and how can I fix this error?

Comment: When you downvote the question please comment why

Comment: i did upvote ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code i submitted before wasn't running , but this does in the browser and gives you hello world.
I have installed extra package called `ejs-loader` 
(due to ejs extension , i guess, it wasn't getting document node)
this is your webpack config **UPDATED**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

var config = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
    filename: "bundle.min.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Showcase",
      template: "./src/index.ejs",
      inject: true,
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src")],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      { test: /\.ejs$/, loader: "ejs-loader?variable=data" }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          priority: -10,
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
        }
      },

      chunks: "async",
      minChunks: 1,
      minSize: 30000,
      name: true
    }
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

this is your tsconfig **UPDATED**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017", "dom"],
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["src/components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

just create a **dist** folder in your root directory

Comment: It really works, now I have to figure out what was wrong in my initial configuration. Thank you.

Comment: okay , glad to hear :)